# Easy to get list name from GUID?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm looking at a Sharepoint 2007 custom layout page that has SPDataSource code referencing a GUID to a list (I assume it's a list). How can I determine the list name from the GUID?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use SiteData.asmx Web Service with Operation: GetListCollection